# Use new to generate an instance of a sub-contract in a smart contract

Tags: solidity, contract-design, contract-deployment

When we write a smart contract, we can use the keyword `new`
in the code to generate an instance of a sub-contract. I want to know whether the instance of this sub-contract has an address, and can external addresses access the instance of this sub-contract?

Hope you can give me some help, thanks!

Comment: Of course it has an address, what else? And other contracts / accounts can access whatever functions are exposed by this contract (public or external). In fact, there is nothing really "sub-contractish" about it, except for the fact that the initial deployer account is the "parent contract".

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I understand the problem.